# Задача по SQL. Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! Задали задачки на дом, почти все решил, но никак не могу решить вот эту задачу. Помогите, пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT lat_n, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY lat_n) nt
    FROM test
    )
SELECT ROUND(lat_n, 4)
FROM cte
WHERE nt = 1
ORDER BY lat_n DESC LIMIT 1;
```